# Increment an output signal in labview

Tags: loops, labview, timed

![enter image description here][1]I have a high voltage control VI and I'd like it to increase the output voltage by a user set increment every x number of seconds. At the moment I have a timed sequence outside the main while loop but it never starts. When it's inside the while loop it delays all other functions. I'm afraid I'm such a beginner at this that I can't post a picture yet. All that needs to happen is an increase in voltage by x amount every y seconds. Is  there a way to fix this or a better way of doing it? I'm open to suggestions! Thanks!

Comment: Why do you need a while loop? You should just need a single timed loop unless your output need to be "held on" by LabVIEW which would be weird. Please post a picture of your code.

Answer (score 1):

Eric,

Without seeing the code I am guessing that you have the two loops in series (i.e. the starting of the while loop depends upon an output of the timed loop; this is the only way that one loop might block another).  If this is the case, then decouple the two loops so that they are not directly dependent on each other.

If the while loop is dependent on user input, then use an event structure and then pass the new parameters via a queue (this would be your producer-consumer pattern).

Also, get rid of the timed loop and replace with a while loop.  The timed loop is only simulated on non-real time machines and it can disrupt determinisitic features of a real-time system. Given that you are looking for sending out a a signal on the order of seconds, it is absolutely not necessary.

Anyways, if I am off base, please throw the code in question up so that we can review it.

Cheers, Matt